# How can with a batch file I create a new folder in certain sub directories, depending on the names of the sub directories

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I have a directory with multiple sub and sub sub directories :
directory/subdirectory/subsubdirectory

Some of these subsubdirectories are called "name", other aren't. In the "name" directories, I want to create a new directory, which is always the same.
I have written this code in a batch file placed in the main directory :

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    if "%%~ni" == Flank do(
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\0 
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\6.5 
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\11     
    )
)
```

However this  code creates the Diffractometry folder everywhere and not only in the subdirectories called "Flank".

Do you know what I could do to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes found:

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    if "%%~ni" == "Flank" (
        rem       ^     ^       quotes and invalid `do` in `if`
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\0 
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\6.5 
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\11     
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```dos
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    if "%%~ni"=="Flank" (
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\0 
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\6.5 
        mkdir %%i\Diffractometry\11     
    )
)
```

Or

```dos
for /r %%i in (Flank) (
    if exist "%%~fi\" for %%a in (0 6.5 11) do md "%%~fi\Diffractometry\%%a"
)
```

In any case

- `for` command needs the `do` clause but the `if` command does not use it.
- When comparing string values, the quotes are included in the operation, so both sides of the comparision should include the quotes, else the values will not match.
- The `mkdir` or `md` commands create the full indicated hierarchy, you can directly create the deeper subfolder and all parents will be generated if needed.